# Write output to $file (allowing it to be stdout)

Tags: bash, shell, unix, command-line, sh

Suppose I have this script:

```
logfile=$1
echo "This is just a debug message indicating the script is starting to run..."

# Do some work...

echo "Results: x, y and z." >> $logfile
```

Is it possible to invoke the script from the command-line such that `$logfile` is actually stdout?

---

Why? I would like to have a script that prints *part of* its output to stdout or, optionally, to a file.

"But why not remove the `>> $logfile` part and just invoke it with `./script >> filename` when you want to write to a file?", you may ask.

Well, because I just want to do this "optional redirect" thing for some output messages. In the example above, just the second message should be affected.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `/dev/stdout`, if your operating system is Linux or something similarly compliant with convention. Or:

```
#!/bin/bash

# works on bash even if OS doesn't provide a /dev/stdout
# for non-bash shells, consider using exec 3>&1 explicitly if $1 is empty
exec 3>${1:-/dev/stdout}

echo "This is just a debug message indicating the script is starting to run..." >&2
echo "Results: x, y and z." >&3
```

This is also **vastly** more efficient than putting `>>"$filename"` on every line that should log to the file, which reopens the file for output on each command.

Comment: Ah! This is awesome, thanks! I can just create these file descriptors on the fly, inside a script? (As I understand, there are only 3 by default -- stdin, stdout and stderr).

Comment: Agreed, i would do `exec 3>${1:-/dev/stdout}`.

Comment: @bufh, granted, bash will always recognize `/dev/stdout`, even when there's no literal `/dev` entry for it, but not all shells are bash, and not all operating systems have a `/dev/stdout`.

Comment: PS: I really appreciate the quick reply. Too bad I can't accept your answer yet :P

Comment: @dsetton yes, actually on Linux you will see the file descriptors of your programs in `/proc/$PID/fd/`, firefox will have a hundred of them...

Comment: @dsetton, incidentally, on bash 4.1 or newer, you can ask the shell itself to pick an available file descriptor number for you. `exec {fd_num}>filename`, and then the number will be in `"$fd_num"`, ready to be used in `>&"$fd_num"`.

Comment: That's really cool! Just learned a lot more than I had hoped :D

Comment: (BTW, I  put the `>&2` on the status message because, well, stderr is where debug and status messages are _supposed to go by convention_. Perhaps if you followed that convention, you could run your script with `>>filename` and not need `$1` handling after all).

Comment: @bufh, ...on second thought, ended up adopting your suggestion; it's not like I wasn't using bashisms already, after all. :)

Comment: @CharlesDuffy that's interesting, I've always thought of stderr as a stream that should be used exclusively for *errors*, ie, something that would cause the program to exit with non-zero status. Never thought that was the place for plain debug messages too.

Comment: @dsetton, keep in mind that stdout is what goes into a pipeline. If you're piping your output to a program that's processing it, do you want to have to write that program to filter out your debug logs and status? If you look at the POSIX spec, you'll also see numerous examples of content written to stderr in non-erroneous cases: Even the prompt messages from the shell itself go there! Numerous tools are specified as only sending "diagnostic messages" to stderr, but such messages need not be fatal -- a log message is very much diagnostic in nature.